# C# Visual Studio 2008 - SQLite Update loop

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm using C# and quite new to SQLite .

I need to update the record field "Value1" by dividing it by a given denominator for a Certain User and date range (First record date to a spicific Date eg. 2012-03-01).

So I need to loop through the data set and if User=John and Date <= than 2012-03-01 then divide Value1 by lets say 10

This obviously can't be done in SQL alone as I need to know what Value1 is, so that I can devided it. How would I go about doing this ?

Below is a example of what data I need to modify

```
User | Date        | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
----------------------------------------------
John | 2012-01-01  |  *50   |  5     |  80
John | 2012-02-01  |  *100  |  78    |  60 
John | 2012-03-01  |  *10   |  100   |  5
John | 2012-04-01  |  5     |  89    |  55
John | 2012-05-01  |  15    |  50    |  44
Max  | 2012-01-01  |  40    |  25    |  90
Max  | 2012-02-01  |  99    |  79    |  30 
Max  | 2012-03-01  |  100   |  110   |  59
Max  | 2012-04-01  |  25    |  29    |  85
Max  | 2012-05-01  |  15    |  30    |  88
```

Modified data divided by 10

```
User | Date        | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
----------------------------------------------
John | 2012-01-01  |  *5    |  5     |  80
John | 2012-02-01  |  *10   |  78    |  60 
John | 2012-03-01  |  *1    |  100   |  5
John | 2012-04-01  |  5     |  89    |  55
John | 2012-05-01  |  15    |  50    |  44
Max  | 2012-01-01  |  40    |  25    |  90
Max  | 2012-02-01  |  99    |  79    |  30 
Max  | 2012-03-01  |  100   |  110   |  59
Max  | 2012-04-01  |  25    |  29    |  85
Max  | 2012-05-01  |  15    |  30    |  88
```

If Value1 was constant then I could use the code below. But it is'nt and it will update 2012-01-01 to 2012-03-01 Value1 will all be 5.

```
Value1 = 50
Val = Value1 / 10

sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
sql_cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Tablename SET Value1= '"+Val+"' WHERE User = 'John' and Date <= '2012-03-01'";
sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: `"UPDATE Tablename SET Value1=Value1 / 10 WHERE User = 'John' and Date <= '2012-03-01'";`

Comment: Roger you are a star.... It worked . Man I have to get a book on SQLite 3

Comment: Roger could I bother you one last time. Is there a way I can edit that SQL statment so that it reads "on 2012-03-01 if Value1=10" then "UPDATE Tablename SET Value1=Value1 / 10 WHERE User = 'John' and Date <= '2012-03-01'";

Answer (score 0):

You really need to brush up on your SQL syntax, but generally, if you want to use fileds in the current row in an `UPDATE` statement, you can just put the equation (or string function or whatever is appropriate) in the `UPDATE` statement itself.

So, for your example, to divide `Value1` by 10 for a particular row (or set of rows):

```
UPDATE Tablename SET Value1 = Value1/10 WHERE User = 'John' and Date <= '2012-03-01'
```

From your latest comment above, if you need additional conditions to select different rows, put those in the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE Tablename SET Value1 = 1 WHERE User = 'John' and Date <= '2012-03-01' and Value1 = 10
```

So, maybe do some reading about SQL syntax generally (it's a big subject) and then repost any specific questions about syntax.